# template non type arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, arguments, linkage

> > $14.3.2 - "... A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> ...a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and **external or internal** linkage or a function with external or internal linkage..."

In the code shown below, I fail to understand why 'name2' and 'name3' are not allowed as non type template arguments. I am using gcc 4.7.2 on Windows.

Both 'name2' and 'name3' are names of array and hence are constant expressions. Further 'name2' is having internal linkage and 'name3' has both static and internal linkage.

```
template<char const *p> void f()
{

}

char name1[] = "Hi";
static char name2[]= "Hi";
const static char name3[]= "Hi";
char *name4 = "Hi";

int main()
{
    f<name1>();
    f<name2>();
    f<name3>();
    f<name4>();
}
```

Comment: Does it `char *name4 = "Hi";` compile?

Comment: @Nawaz yes `error: 'name4' is not a valid template argument because 'name4' is a variable, not the address of a variable`

Comment: @Nawaz: No. name4 is not a constant expression and is instead a variable name.

Comment: @Chubsdad: Yes. I was thinking that. It should not compile!

Comment: BTW, it appears to be a compiler bug which seems to be silly to me.

Comment: @Nawaz you are probably right, [clang](http://liveworkspace.org/code/JDZqy$46) seems relatively fine with it

Comment: @Nawaz yup, without `name4` it [compiles](http://liveworkspace.org/code/JDZqy$50)

Comment: @KarthikT: I think *that* is the answer to this question. Post it.

Comment: hmm, I can't make it work with VS2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Nawaz correctly guessed, this is an implementation bug, not an esoteric corner of the standard.

Specifically, gcc seems to have trouble with it. Barring the last `name4` which is against the standard, the rest of it compiles fine with [clang](http://liveworkspace.org/code/JDZqy%2450)

Comment: Guessed so. But now I am curious as to why string literals are not allowed. In C++03 they weren't allowed as they had internal linkage (as in C++11 too). So, String literals seem to satisfy all the criteria of the third bullet in this section

Comment: @Chubsdad: string literals are not allowed probably because everytime you use a string literal of same value, they are not necessarily *identical* string i.e they might have different address. Means, `bool b = ("hello" == "hello")` *might* give you `false`!

Comment: @KonradRudolph: No, they're not allowed. See §14.3.2/1 (n3483).

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, of course. Blame R. Martinho in the chat, he mis-informed me. ;-)

Comment: +1 Goodness! I had not noticed that you could pick clang 3.2 on liveworkspace :D

Comment: @Nawaz: I have asked the question about string literals https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/DkDWRYQ4Vw0

Comment: @Chubsdad: Great! I believe you will get similar replies as I said in my previous comment, or at least that is one of the reason. Lets see what others say.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is that the expression you use are not actually pointers but arrays, and the pointer decay only works for `name1`. It is most likely a compiler bug, as kindly @KonradRudolph pointed out in the comment, section 14.3.2 of the C++11 standard allows it, and there is nothing essentially different between `name1`, `name2` and `name3`.

As a workaround, the following will compile with GCC 4.7.2 using `-std=c++11`:

```
template<char const *p> void f()
{
}

char name1[] = "Hi";
static char name2[]= "Hi";
const static char name3[]= "Hi";

int main()
{
    f<(char const*)&name1>();
    f<(char const*)&name2>();
    f<(char const*)&name3>();
}
```

In C++98 mode it does not compile because the result of a cast is never a constant expression, while in C++11 it may be.

Comment: Why shouldn’t automatic pointer decay work here? I suspect the compiler bug is the other way round. The arrays certainly have the correct linkage and are constant expressions; I see no reason why they shouldn’t work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You may very well be right! I cannot find in the standard any reference to automatic decay being used in constant expressions. Maybe it is implicitly specified elsewere, but I the constant expression requirements are a bit... let's say 'dense'.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Right, it even gives an example similar to this one. Answer updated.