# Constexpr construction and static member is not working

Tags: c++, c++11, static-methods, constexpr

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Type>
class Test
{
    public:
        constexpr Test(const Type val) : _value(val) {}
        constexpr Type get() const {return _value;}
        static void test()
        {
            static constexpr Test<int> x(42);
            std::integral_constant<int, x.get()> i;
            std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        }
    protected:
        Type _value;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test<double>::test();
    return 0;
}
```

Under g++ 4.7.1, it returns the error:

```
main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Test<Type>::test()’:
main.cpp:13:48: error: invalid use of ‘Test<Type>::get<int>’ to form a pointer-to-member-function
main.cpp:13:48: note:   a qualified-id is required
main.cpp:13:48: error: could not convert template argument ‘x.Test<Type>::get<int>()’ to ‘int’
main.cpp:13:51: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

I do not understand the problem: is it a compiler bug or is it a real problem ?
How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [GCC bug](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1pINqc%242), clang 3.2 [compiles without any error](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1pINqc%240)

Comment: What about MSVC? Oh wait, `constexpr`, hah!

Comment: Ok, I just added the bug to the g++ bugtracker : http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55931

Comment: @Vincent thanks, am a little dissapointed in GCC though, [2nd bug in 3 days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192936/template-non-type-arguments/14193677#comment19676817_14193677)